# How to program the Enter button to allow two actions, either correct or wrong?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I'm creating a word game,

I need my Check/Enter button to do three functions.

Correct = if the right word is correct then the button should make the custom keyboard disappear.

Wrong = if the answer is wrong the keyboard should remain on screen.

```
- (IBAction)btncheck:(id)sender {
}
```

Comment: You can use an `if` statement. :)

Comment: yeah, a little detail would help a ton!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is a little too broad but all you need is add a check to your `IBAction`.

```
- (IBAction)btncheck:(id)sender {
   if(isValid){
     //correct
     [self.textfield resignFirstResponder];
   }else{
     //Wrong
   }
}
```

Comment: I did it: - (IBAction)btncheck:(id)sender {
    
    // Enter has been pressed, see if the text in the textView equals our string
    if ([_textbox.text isEqualToString:@"q"]) {
        // String is correct, resign keyboard
        _keyboard.hidden = YES;
    }
    else {
        // Was not correct.  Notify user, or just don't do anything
    }